# Create new line/carriage return on paragraph after more than 1 spaces

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to create carriage return/start in new line after more than 3 spaces in a single line of paragraph in Javascript. Thank You

Comment: Give a key down event to the paragraph. Track the spaces and if its count is 3 then trigger enter event. If the content is already there, then iterate and append

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Are you dealing with a content editable element or maybe with textarea, or something else?

Comment: I'm using indexOf to count the number of spaces on the given data from host(mainframe)then will start a new line after I hit more than 1 spaces then display the host message on the web browser using Javascript, is there a way to increment a spaces??how? Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, got it.. I used the regular expression  below to check the spaces then carriage return & new line for more than 2 spaces. thanks                                                      var sChecktemp = sChecktemp .replace(/\s{2,}/g, "\r\n");

Answer (score 1):

It would help  if you posted your code, but if you want to parse a block of text and reformat it, how about this:

```
var string = //paragraph text;
var newStr = string.replace(/ {3,}/g, '<br>');
```

Then replace `string` with `newsStr`.